# matrix algebra with invertibles

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Im asked to solve for X given the equation
$$
(A^{-1}X)^{-1} = (AB^{-1})^{-1}(AB^2)
$$
What I have done so far is:
$$
((A^{-1}X)^{-1})^{-1} = ((AB^{-1})^{-1}(AB^2))^{-1}
\\A^{-1}X = ((AB^{-1})^{-1}(AB^2))^{-1}
\\A^{-1}X = AB^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-2}
\\AA^{-1}X = AAB^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-2}
\\X=A^2B^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-2}
$$
Is this correct or did I preform something that is not true? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third step is wrong. Note that $(XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$

$\\A^{-1}X = ((AB^{-1})^{-1}(AB^2))^{-1}
\\A^{-1}X = B^{-2}A^{-1}AB^{-1}
\\A^{-1}X = B^{-3}
\\X=AB^{-3}
$

Comment: Yes thank you. I see now, forgot about the laws of inverses. This may help people later on: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ If you are multiplying two matrices instead of $AB$ then remember the product of the two matrices will be another matrix. So that: $((AB)(CD))^{-1}=(CD)^{-1}(AB)^{-1}$